# How to add custom font in FPDI with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, fpdf

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI) pkg with Laravel... so i want to add custom font.

my code:

```
$pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddFont('SuisseIntl-Regular', '', public_path('fonts/suisseIntl-segular.php'));
$pdf->setSourceFile('PdfDocument.pdf');
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

$pdf->SetFont('SuisseIntl-Regular');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');
$pdf->Output('I', 'generated.pdf');
```

I went to [this](http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/index.php) website and download two files `suisseIntl-regular.php` and `SuisseIntl-Regular.z`, I put them in `public/fonts/...` dir

I got this error:

```
FPDF error: Incorrect font definition file name: /Users/a/Documents/Sites/w-c-backend/public/fonts/suisseIntl-segular.php
```

even the suisseIntl-regular.php is there:(

Comment: Your string reads: `'fonts/suisseIntl-segular.php'`, with an "s", not: `'fonts/suisseIntl-regular.php'`, with an "r". Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware no it is the correct name but got same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of [`AddFont()`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/addfont.htm) accepts only a file name (not a full path). To specify the directory where the font is located, use the 4th parameter:

```
$pdf->AddFont('SuisseIntl-Regular', '', 'suisseIntl-segular.php', public_path('fonts'));
```